# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, node-fetch, hypixel-api

I'm trying to make a [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(software)) bot that just says if someone is online on the game.

However I keep getting this message:

> [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module from not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in... to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

This is my code:

```js
    module.exports = {
        name: 'username',
        description: "this is the username command",
        async execute(message, args) {

            const fetch = require('node-fetch');

            if (args.length !== 1) {
                return message.channel.send("invalid username wtf")
            }

            const ign = args[0]

            if (ign.length > 16 || ign.length < 3) {
                return message.channel.send("invalid username wtf")
            }

            const uuid = await fetch(`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/${ign}`).then(data => data.json()).then(data => data.id).catch(err => message.channel.send("error wtf"));
            const onlineInfo = await fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/status?key=${john}&uuid=${uuid}`).then(data => data.json());

            if (uuid.length !== 32) {
                return;
            }

            if (onlineinfo.success) {
                if (onlineinfo.session.online) {
                    message.channel.send("they are online")
                }
                else {
                    message.channel.send("they are offline")
                }
            }
            else {
                message.channel.send("hypixel api bad wtf")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my *package.json* file:

```json
{
    "name": "discordbot",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node main.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "description": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "discord.js": "^13.0.1",
        "node-fetch": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have all the module.exports stuff, do I need that? I just say export class whatever, is that wrong?

Comment: But I thought `"type": "module",` should only be used IF you didn't rename your files as *.mjs*.

Comment: In my case it was about the way I'd compiled using `npx tsc app.ts` while this won't pick the configuration file (tsconfig.json), use just `npx tsc` instead. :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`node-fetch` v3 recently stopped support for the `require` way of importing it in favor of ES Modules. You'll need to use ESM imports now, like:

```js
import fetch from "node-fetch";
```

at the top of your file.

Comment: I already do this, and it doesn't help.

Comment: To be able to import it you need to follow the steps in this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69089164/12152456

Comment: A blessing of an answer. Scratching my head for 30 minutes before stumbling up on this answer that solved  my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Error: "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: @pabrams: this link help me https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-error-err-require-esm-of-es-module-node-fetch

Comment: It's absolutely absurd that all package dependencies need to use the same module import type as the running app. How the Node.js developers thought that breaking backward compatibility in an ecosystem where everything depends of everything would work well is beyond me.

Comment: i got error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Answer (score 98):

The `node-fetch` latest version doesn't use the `require()` syntax to import the package. You need to go to your `package.json` and type

```
 { 
   "type": "module",
 }
```

to use the `import` syntax and import `node-fetch`, but then you can't use `require` for any other packages. You need to work with `import` statement only.

Or you can use other packages, such as [Got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) or [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), which can be imported by the `require()` syntax.

Comment: I use require() in a different file in my code, so how come it works there?

Comment: I already do this, but I still get the error, because the typescript transpiler puts the requires back, in the .js.  How do I get it to stop doing that?

Comment: doesn't work, still throws Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported. Although i don't have a single require() in my code anymore.

Comment: once i add this to my package.json will i still be able to use require for other packages?

Comment: Can they work together? ES Module and CommonJS? I thought this was done by the extension (*.mjs* /vs/ *.js*)

Comment: Same, this doesn't work because the typescript transpiler adds requires.

Comment: `got` v12 doesn't work with `require()`, you have to use `import`. "This package is native ESM and no longer provides a CommonJS export. If your project uses CommonJS, you'll have to convert to ESM or use the dynamic import() function."

Comment: what do you mean by "type {type: module}", where exactly in the package.json should we do it?

Answer (score 80):

I figured it out. I just had to downgrade `node-fetch` to 2.6.6, as the higher versions only use ESM, which caused a lot of errors.

Comment: When I try that, I get compile time errors from typescript, like it can't import node-fetch, can't find node-fetch, can't find type definitions for node-fetch, blah blah blah... and then if I add the type definitions it says I don't need those... wtf is up with typescript and node all the time

Comment: You then need to import like this `import * as fetch from 'node-fetch';`

Comment: Still works. Still dumb.

Comment: This is so stupid. Why don't import an require just not work together nicely...

Comment: What is ESM? [ECMAScript module](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/)?

Comment: Make sure you delete your node_modules folder and package-lock.json file after updating package.json. 

Then you should be able to run npm install and have it working