# How to let a CJS package dynamically require an ES module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, commonjs

I'm using a *loader* package to which I pass the name of a *loadee* module and it `require()`s it.

The *loader* uses CJS's `require()` to dynamically require the *loadee*, but the *loadee* is an ES module. Because of this Node.js throws an error.

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module LOADEE from LOADER not supported.
Instead change the require of LOADEE in LOADER to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Neither the *loader* or the *loadee* are managed by me, so I can't modify them. I can't avoid using them either.

I can of course write an intermediary *loadee*, written in CJS (so the *loader* can load it), which then loads the true *loadee* and passes it back to the *loader*. But I don't know how to do it, since the dynamic `import()` is async (returns a promise), but the *loader*'s `require()` is sync and expects the loaded module immediately.

Is there anything else I can do to make this thing work?

#### Example to show what's happening

In case the description I gave is not clear enough, I'm trying to post some minimal snippets of code to show what's happening:

###### LOADER (CJS; not written by me)

```
module.exports = function(pkg) {
  const x = require(pkg)
  console.log(x)
}
```

###### LOADEE (ES Module; not written by me)

```
default export const x = 1
```

###### ./index.js (this one is mine: I can choose CJS or ES Module or anything else)

```
import load from 'LOADER'
load('LOADEE')
```

When I run `node ./index.js` this is what I get:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module LOADEE from LOADER not supported.
Instead change the require of LOADEE in LOADER to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

#### Similar questions

I already found similar questions on stack overflow. For instance:

- [Error: require() of ES modules is not supported when importing node-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041454/error-require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-when-importing-node-fetch)
- [Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported)

They explain how to use `import()` to dynamically import a module. But that doesn't help me since I cannot change the `require()` call in the *loader* and don't know how to wrap it with an async dynamic `import()`.

Is there anything I can do to make this thing work?

Comment: I'd first say that the loader design you have is just not the right design for ESM modules since there is no dynamic and synchronous import.  So, I think you're better off going back a few design steps and sharing why you got to the place you did where you're trying to do dynamic and synchronous imports.  You probably  need to replace that with a different design.  But, you don't share any of that with us, so we can't really comment on a better architecture for the higher problem that your code is attempting to solve.

Comment: @jfriend00: I have no control on the loader (nor on the loadee). It's a package my company uses and I can't replace it (not easily at least). I agree that it's a bad design, but what can I do? I'm looking for a workaround to get things to work again.

Comment: Well, that design is not compatible with ESM modules.  So, I think you're going to have to question some assumptions/requirements you're being dealt.  For a variety of reasons, synchronous loading of ESM modules is restricted to statically declared modules (not dynamic imports).  As you seem to already know dynamic ESM imports are asynchronous.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that... Isn't there any secret flag to beg node to let me `require()` ESM? Or maybe as a last resort I can do something crazy like use some module-bundler to build the *loadee* into a CJS module?

Comment: No secrets I know of.  See this [Node Modules at War: Why CommonJS and ES Modules Can’t Get Along](https://redfin.engineering/node-modules-at-war-why-commonjs-and-es-modules-cant-get-along-9617135eeca1) for a pretty detailed list of what you can and can't do.

Comment: You cannot have a variable called `package` in your loader, that's a reserved keyword. Also does the function exported by the loader not return any value?

Comment: @GOTO0: I'm renaming the variable. This is not my actual code, I don't have a problem with any variable called package. It was a very minimal snippet to show what's happening. That's the same reason why the loader does nothing: there's no problem with the computation, but with `require()`.

Comment: @BlueNebula I mean, if the loader does not return a value, you won't be able to use the value `x = 1` exported by the loadee in your index.js. So do you need the loadee only for the side effects it produces when it gets evaluated?

Comment: @GOTO0: fine, I updated the example: now the *loader* is using the value the *loadee* exports. What I provided is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show the issue. Tho *loader*, *loadee* and my code are actually more complicated than that, but the extra complication isn't relevant to the issue I'm facing.