# node JS: App is not working after deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

this is my first project in node js and it worked perfect on localhost but when i deployed it on heroku it's not working and shows application error,, i couldn't figure out what is the problem and below is my heroku logs and server.js code.
can someone please help me solve this?

thanks in advance

```js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const http = require('http');
const multer = require("multer");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);


// corsfffffffff



/************************************** Socket IO Related Start ************************************************/

// config dotenv
dotenv.config();


const dbURI = process.env.MONGO_URL || "mongodb+srv://user:cvcvcv00S-@cluster0.jpij0.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(result => server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000) )
 
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json);


// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

const subscribersRouter = require('./routes/subscribers')
app.use('/subscribers', subscribersRouter)
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.send("welcome to app");
})
```

heroku logs:

```html
2021-12-09T19:50:00.133986+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-09T19:50:00.134003+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:50:00.134003+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:50:00.134003+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:50:01.187253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:50:32.260199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=cfbf2688-d4d4-4b7a-adf0-2663a1d7dace fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:50:43.082048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:50:43.107251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:50:43.871385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:50:44.069113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=49445fee-a0d0-4199-9adb-bf4314016e98 fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11418ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:50:44.193647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:50:45.155711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:50:46.561346+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:50:46.561360+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:50:46.561361+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:50:46.561361+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:50:47.295414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:51:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:52:08.296910+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 202801b6 by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:52:08.296910+00:00 app[api]: Release v44 created by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:52:08.590301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:52:08.615504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:52:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-09T19:52:09.331866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:52:09.574745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:52:10.680588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:52:11.875404+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:52:11.875420+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:52:11.875420+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:52:11.875420+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:52:12.491955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:53:21.013488+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=3d66d37c-eec6-44d2-8792-a7ddff579766 fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:53:41.188552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:53:41.191420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:53:41.978236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:53:42.180105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=98bb6ae6-b3ec-4206-95a4-6279e7aff78b fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20953ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:53:42.314257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:53:43.672529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:53:45.699311+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:53:45.699323+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:53:45.699324+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:53:45.699324+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:53:47.034852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:57:01.713660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:57:01.847677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:57:02.852486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:57:03.172988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:57:04.132727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:57:05.215604+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:57:05.215618+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:57:05.215618+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:57:05.215618+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:57:05.821299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:57:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:57:30.843649+00:00 app[api]: Release v45 created by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:57:30.843649+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 338ae6f5 by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:57:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-09T19:57:31.085978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:57:31.201283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:57:31.880715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:57:32.065101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:57:33.428958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:57:34.677151+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:57:34.677180+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:57:34.677181+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:57:34.677181+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:57:35.761777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:58:08.215698+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=51f7029d-58a6-445a-a111-a77bccfa90c0 fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:58:38.614677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=56500d70-9535-4cdf-8665-2cfe463b908d fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T20:05:25.879914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=e7ff010a-b9b7-49e8-bae6-b72eb0794c0e fwd="34.204.52.120" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2021-12-09T20:07:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:07:34.550502+00:00 app[api]: Release v46 created by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:07:34.550502+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 274eee09 by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:07:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-09T20:07:38.124510+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T20:07:38.227065+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T20:07:39.027871+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T20:07:39.245964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T20:07:40.890971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T20:07:42.140238+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T20:07:42.140265+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T20:07:42.140265+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T20:07:42.140266+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T20:07:43.221265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T20:08:14.814637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=afc72089-87b7-4d01-a2dd-a0efddfc3d62 fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T20:08:45.157453+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=b38528cf-d42d-4184-b52b-6808444e99bd fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T20:13:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:14:15.262368+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fe24fd44 by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:14:15.262368+00:00 app[api]: Release v47 created by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:14:15.498236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T20:14:15.523576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T20:14:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-09T20:14:16.770111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T20:14:17.043608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T20:14:17.959793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T20:14:19.191029+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T20:14:19.191041+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T20:14:19.191041+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T20:14:19.191042+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T20:14:19.891841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install all the modules using `npm install --save <module>`? If you don't include the `--save` option, then the module won't be written to your `package.json` file which Heroku uses to automatically download the dependencies.

Comment: Also, you should censor MongoDB URIs.

Comment: yes i did to all of them, but if i want to make sure can i install them again?

Comment: Open your `package.json` file and check if `node-fetch` is included in the dependencies.

Comment: i updated the question after running `heroku logs` again

Comment: `node-fetch` doesn't allow `require()` anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported

Comment: i deleted the module since i'm not using it and nothing changed after pushing to heroku

Comment: It can't find the `request` module, but I suspect your `./routes/subscribers` module, not your main module.

Comment: i uninstalled the request module as well but still application error appears, please check the edited `heroku logs`

Comment: `npm install` does `--save` by default since [version 5.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.0.0) (May, 2017).