# I have an error message when launching an express app

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have this code, that should normally work :

```
import express from "express";
import nunjucks from "nunjucks";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

nunjucks.configure("views", {
  autoescape: true,
  express: app,
});
app.set("view engine", "njk");

app.get("/", (req, response) => {
  fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) =>
      console.log(data)
      // response.render("home", { categories: data }
    )
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

but when I try to run it with `ts-node src/index.ts`, i have this error :

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop/CODE/sw-api/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js from /mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop/CODE/sw-api/src/index.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop/CODE/sw-api/src/index.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop/CODE/sw-api/src/index.ts:9:36)
    at Module.m._compile (/mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop/CODE/sw-api/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:735:29)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop/CODE/sw-api/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:737:16)
    at main (/mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop/CODE/sw-api/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:238:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop/CODE/sw-api/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:351:5) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

I don't quite understand, cause i don't use require() to import my modules

Could anyone help me ? Thank you

Comment: Your TypeScript build configuration may be generating CJS modules with `require()`, not EJS modules with `import`.  That's where you need to check.  You can also look at the generated Javascript source code that is actually executing and you will probably see the `require()` in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't, try updating `package.json` with `"type": "module"`. Also take a look at the following: [Error: require() of ES modules is not supported when importing node-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041454/error-require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-when-importing-node-fetch) and [Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported).