# Replacing JS require('...') with ESM imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

After updating `node-fetch` to v3, the following JavaScript error message appears when trying to launch my Electron app:

Uncaught Exception:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module (...) not supported.
Instead change the required ... to a dynamic import() ...

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported) that I should replace

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

with:

```
import fs from "fs";
```

But how to replace in the same fashion the following?

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {
  app,
  session,
  BrowserWindow
} = require('electron');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you would do this as you have done it with `fs` and would do with other ES modules:

```
import { app, session, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
```

However, I don't believe you can do this directly with Electron as it's a [CommonJS module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) and not all the modules are directly named as exports.

You should be able to import what you need via the default import however:

```
import electron from "electron";
const { app, session, BrowserWindow } = electron;
```

Answer (score 0):

U need replace package name with variable or functions with brackets around them

`import { app, session, BrowserWindow } from "electron";`

This will work for sure