# How to import 'into-stream' package?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const inMemoryStorage = multer.memoryStorage();
const uploadStrategy = multer({ storage: inMemoryStorage }).single('image');
const { BlockBlobClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const getStream = require('into-stream');
```

I can't use require in importing 'into-stream' module, it gives me ESM error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
```

I tried adding type:module in package.json however require will not work if I do that. Do I install another version of into-stream? or should I use import rather than require. I am using node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package doesn't support require() anymore, just like node-fetch mentioned at this thread:

[Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported)

You should add type: "module" to your package.json and then use:

```
import getStream from "into-stream";
```

I suggest you put that in the top of your file, just for code style :x

If this doesn't work, downgrade to version 6.0.0, which works with require(), according to the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/into-stream/v/6.0.0

Comment: If I added type: "module" , should i change all modules to import aswell? since require doesnt work. Or should I just downgrade the version?

Comment: You could change them all, it would make sense, but only if you want to. I even recommend, ES Modules is the standard for Javascript, CommonJS was the standard only for Node.js