# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module, node_modules\wrap-ansi\index.js not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

In a nestjs project I'm facing issues with a library I'm not dicrectly using in my code but it's used by third-party.

> stringWidth = require('string-width') in
> node_modules\wrap-ansi\index.js:2 not supported

Here is package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.9.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.1.2",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.1.2",
    "@nestjs/event-emitter": "^2.0.2",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.2",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.1.2",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.1.4",
    "@nestjs/throttler": "^4.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0",
    "@ttshivers/automapper-classes": "^8.8.3",
    "@ttshivers/automapper-core": "^8.8.3",
    "@ttshivers/automapper-nestjs": "^8.8.3",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.7",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-custom": "^1.1.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.1.11",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.1.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.3",
    "@types/node": "20.4.5",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.35",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "29.6.2",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^4.4.7"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@application/(.*)": "<rootDir>/application/$1",
      "@domain/(.*)": "<rootDir>/domain/$1",
      "@infrastructure/(.*)": "<rootDir>/infrastructure/$1"
    }
  }
```

The latest packages I've installed when I noticed the issue was:

```
@nestjs-modules/mailer
nodemailer
handlebars
@types/nodemailer
```

The issue I'm facing running any nest command is this:

[image: stack trace of error here]

Based on similar posts, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041454/error-require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-when-importing-node-fetch) an [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported), I tried by adding "type": "module" in package.json but not success. Also, I removed node_modules and reinstall packages (yarn) and this is what I get:

[image]

same error: `var stringWidth = require('string-width')` but in different file: `node_modules\wide-align\align.js:2`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Upvoted. I also have similar issues :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77592704/jest-fails-to-run-after-installing-selenium-webdriver/77592734#77592734

Answer (score 26):

I have the same issue and this helped me to solve this problem

Add this to your package.json file

```
"resolutions": {
  "wrap-ansi": "7.0.0",
  "string-width": "4.1.0"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem as well and tried this solution. It somewhat works, but do you know why?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77592704/jest-fails-to-run-after-installing-selenium-webdriver/77592734#77592734

Comment: Hey, I managed to solve my issue in this way as well, it works because when your project installs dependencies, the package manager first looks at the`resolutions` field. If there are any versions specified for any dependencies in the `resolutions`, it will prioritize those versions installed.

Comment: @Matthew but how did you know those specific versions will resolve it?

Comment: It's resolved because these are versions before these modules go full esm.

Comment: Thank you! I was running into this issue for a while!

Comment: You are awesome!
This has plagued me for some time.

Answer (score 14):

I've had the same issue after upgrading the system to macOS Sonoma 14.2.1.

My solution is:

Remove yarn.lock file and yarn install again fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, this is the fix!

Comment: To me this method only works once, if I restart the program the same issue still occurs, adding "resolutions" in `package.json` as suggested in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77465601/8581245) fix it permanently

Answer (score 4):

I achieved to solve this issue but as a workaround. What I did was to clean Yarn cache, remove yarn.lock, remove node-modules, and I reinstalled all packages from scratch. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

I added this to *package.json*

```
"resolutions": {
  "wrap-ansi": "7.0.0",
  "string-width": "4.1.0"
}
```

and after that I needed to delete *node_modules* remove *yarn.lock* and *yarn install* again

Answer (score 0):

Update: Time later it started to bother me again this issue, so according some blogs found in internet, I decided to discard using yarn and I switched back to npm and it's working now because it seems this issue is related to a bug in yarn. In some places recommend to upgrade yarn 1 to 3 but the upgrading process come up with issues, so I prefer to keep with npm.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when I was running NestJS project with docker and I was able to solve it by deleting the `yarn.lock` file and never copy it in the app directory in `Dockfile`.

Here is the example of the line I removed in the `Dockfile`

```
COPY --chown=node:node yarn.lock ./
```

Comment: This is not a solution. yarn.lock fine is an important part of the application that defines the versions of your dependencies. If you remove it you may get different version of dependencies with each build resulting into undeterministic behavior.